# How to copy an array in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, copy

I have an array of applications, initialized like this:

```
depends=$(cat ~/Depends.txt)
```

When I try to parse the list and copy it to a new array using,

```
for i in "${depends[@]}"; do
   if [ $i #isn't installed ]; then
      newDepends+=("$i")
   fi
done
```

What happens is that only the first element of depends winds up on newDepends.

```
for i in "${newDepends[@]}"; do
   echo $i
done
```

^^ This would output just one thing. So I'm trying to figure out why my for loop is is only moving the first element. The whole list is originally on depends, so it's not that, but I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: That looks fine to me. Are you sure your "isn't installed" test is working correctly?

Comment: Is there a typo in your question? `depends` will consist of 2 words, `cat` and `~/Depends`, not the contents of `~/Depends.txt`.

Answer (score 199):

```
a=(foo bar "foo 1" "bar two")  #create an array
b=("${a[@]}")                  #copy the array in another one 

for value in "${b[@]}" ; do    #print the new array 
echo "$value" 
done
```

Comment: Is it ok to just write b=(${a[@]}) ?

Comment: try to execute the command with your modifications , you will undestand why it's not correct to write without quoting... the value "foo 1" will not displayed  like it shoudl but it will create more value for the array  foo AND 1 , bar AND two , instead of  "foo 1" and "bar two"

Comment: @Indicator You will have problems with spaces!

Comment: Also works for copying the command line arguments, as in `b=("$@")`.

Comment: this changes the order of  elements if some elements are empty.

Answer (score 60):

The simplest way to copy a non-associative array in bash is to:

```
arrayClone=("${oldArray[@]}")
```

or to add elements to a preexistent array:

```
someArray+=("${oldArray[@]}")
```

Newlines/spaces/IFS in the elements will be preserved.

For copying associative arrays, [Isaac's solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25171698/1091436) work great.

Comment: his did not seem to work for me:
```
$ a1=( big harry man );
$ a2=( "${!a1[@]}" );
$ echo "${a2[0]}";
0
$ echo "${a2[1]}";
1;
$
```

Comment: hey @FelipeAlvarez - indeed the `!` was superfluous, I've corrected my answer

Comment: this changes the order of elements if some elements are empty.

Answer (score 11):

The solutions given in the other answers won't work for associative arrays, or for arrays with non-contiguous indices.  Here are is a more general solution:

```
declare -A arr=([this]=hello [\'that\']=world [theother]='and "goodbye"!')
temp=$(declare -p arr)
eval "${temp/arr=/newarr=}"

diff <(echo "$temp") <(declare -p newarr | sed 's/newarr=/arr=/')
# no output
```

And another:

```
declare -A arr=([this]=hello [\'that\']=world [theother]='and "goodbye"!')
declare -A newarr
for idx in "${!arr[@]}"; do
    newarr[$idx]=${arr[$idx]}
done

diff <(echo "$temp") <(declare -p newarr | sed 's/newarr=/arr=/')
# no output
```

Comment: Your first solution cannot become a function, because `eval "declare -A newarr=…"` will effectively declare a *local* array `newarr` shadowing the real variable from parent environment. It may be an option to remove `declare -A ` so that only `newarr=…` is left, but there are escaping problems down that path.

Comment: Could you explain what you are doing in the one-line solution? What is the                                                                                                                                        pipe in the parentheses for example? thanks

Comment: this worked great to keep the elements in  order

Answer (score 6):

Try this: `arrayClone=("${oldArray[@]}")`

This works easily.

Comment: but not for sparse arrays, that will compress a sparse array

Answer (score 3):

You can copy an array by inserting the elements of the first array into the copy by specifying the index:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=( One Two Three Go! );
array_copy( );

let j=0;
for (( i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++)
do
    if [[ $i -ne 1 ]]; then # change the test here to your 'isn't installed' test
        array_copy[$j]="${array[$i]}
        let i+=1;
    fi
done

for k in "${array_copy[@]}"; do
    echo $k
done
```

The output of this would be:

```
One
Three
Go!
```

A useful document on bash arrays is on [TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html).

Comment: The TLDP site is great, but bash has moved on significantly, and much of what it recommends is now considered bad style.  Unless you are trying to be `bash-2.x` or `dash`/`busybox` compatible, you probably want to find a more recent reference. Hopefully they will update at some point.

Answer (score 3):

```
array_copy() {
    set -- "$(declare -p $1)" "$2"
    eval "$2=${1#*=}"
}

# Usage examples:

these=(apple banana catalog dormant eagle fruit goose hat icicle)
array_copy these those
declare -p those

declare -A src dest
source=(["It's a 15\" spike"]="and it's 1\" thick" [foo]=bar [baz]=qux)
array_copy src dest
declare -p dest
```

Note: when copying associative arrays, the destination must already exist as an associative array. If not, `array_copy()` will create it as a standard array and try to interpret the key names from the associative source as arithmetic variable names, with ugly results.

Isaac Schwabacher's solution is more robust in this regard, but it can't be tidily wrapped up in a function because its `eval` step evaluates an entire `declare` statement and bash treats those as equivalent to `local` when they're inside a function. This could be worked around by wedging the `-g` option into the evaluated `declare` but that might give the destination array *more* scope than it's supposed to have. Better, I think, to have `array_copy()` perform only the actual copy into an explicitly scoped destination.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is to copy array in function to be visible in parent code. This solution works for indexed arrays and if before copying are predefined as `declare -A ARRAY`, works also for associative arrays.

```
function array_copy
# $1 original array name
# $2 new array name with the same content
{
    local INDEX
    eval "
        for INDEX in \"\${!$1[@]}\"
        do
            $2[\"\$INDEX\"]=\"\${$1[\$INDEX]}\"
        done
    "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with [Bash 4.3](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES), you can do this

```
$ alpha=(bravo charlie 'delta  3' '' foxtrot)

$ declare -n golf=alpha

$ echo "${golf[2]}"
delta  3
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. While ```declare -n``` is useful, it only creates a reference to the original array, it doesn't copy it, which is what the question is asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to copy an array into another.

```
firstArray=()
secondArray=()

firstArray+=("Element1")
firstArray+=("Element2")

secondArray+=("${firstArray[@]}")

for element in "${secondArray[@]}"; do
  echo "${element}"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

I've found that this works for me (mostly :)) ...

`eval $(declare -p base | sed "s,base,target,")`

extending the sed command to edit any switches as necessary e.g. if the new structure has to be writeable, to edit out read-only (`-r`).

Answer (score -4):

I've discovered what was wrong.. My if isn't installed test is two for loops that remove excess characters from file names, and spits them out if they exist on a certain web server. What it wasn't doing was removing a trailing hyphen. So, when it tested it online for availability, they were parsed out. Because "file" exists, but "file-" doesn't.