# Deleting random elements from a Bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, random

I'm trying to iterate through a array and dynamically choosing one random element to unset it. I tried the following:

```
a=('red' 'green' 'black' 'yellow' 'white' 'orange' 'blue' 'purple')

while [ ${#a[@]} -ne 0 ]
do
    echo "Length of array:" ${#a[@]}
    randomnumber=$(( ( RANDOM % (${#a[@]}) ) ))
    echo "random number "$randomnumber" -> "${a[$randomnumber]}
    unset a[$randomnumber]
done
```

The length seems to be correct for every loop, but when I'm accessing an element which index has been unset before, the content is empty. I read something about subshell, but have no clue what this means. Does unset really rearrange the array? Can somebody give me a hint how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you unset element 2 element 3 is not the new element 2.

```
# define your array as example
a=('red' 'green' 'black' 'yellow' 'white' 'orange' 'blue' 'purple')

# show array with index in declare's style
declare -p a
```

Output:

```
declare -a a='([0]="red" [1]="green" [2]="black" [3]="yellow" [4]="white" [5]="orange" [6]="blue" [7]="purple")'
```

```
# remove element 2 (black)
unset a[2]
declare -p a
```

Output (no element 2):

```
declare -a a='([0]="red" [1]="green" [3]="yellow" [4]="white" [5]="orange" [6]="blue" [7]="purple")'
```

A possible solution: [copy array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24323275/3776858) to rearrange index:

```
a=("${a[@]}")
declare -p a
```

Output:

```
declare -a a='([0]="red" [1]="green" [2]="yellow" [3]="white" [4]="orange" [5]="blue" [6]="purple")'
```

Comment: + 1 for the lets call it "not-rearrangement-hint" :)

Answer (score 1):

An extract from bash's manpage.

```
The unset builtin is used to  destroy  arrays.   unset  name[subscript]
destroys  the  array element at index subscript.  Care must be taken to
avoid unwanted side effects caused by pathname expansion.  unset  name,
where  name is an array, or unset name[subscript], where subscript is *
or @, removes the entire array.
```

So unset destroys the array element. In memory this is possibly just a pointer movement.

*UPDATE:* Hava a look at this. It seems to lack due to NOT removing references and update the array length in a way $RANDOM returns always a number between 0 and the current length.

```
Length of array: 8
8 random number 7 -> purple
Length of array: 7
7 random number 6 -> blue
Length of array: 6
6 random number 2 -> black
Length of array: 5
5 random number 2 -> 
Length of array: 5
5 random number 0 -> red
```

A possible solution could be to override the array.

*UPDATE:* **The length just changes if you unset array elements that have not been unset yet respecting the initial length**. so you run into an endless loop if you remove element 1, then the length is 7 but with that you are not able to produce a random number 8 anymore. so the length will then be at least 1.

you need to ALWAYS produce random numbers between 0 and 8. additionally you can store indexes that have been removed.

```
length=${#a[@]} # ADD
while [ ${#a[@]} -ne 0 ] 
do
  echo "Length of array:" ${#a[@]}
  randomnumber=$(( $RANDOM % ${#a[@]}  )) # if using this arrange the index afterwards like Cyrus said, avoids the overhead mentioned below
  #randomnumber=$(( $RANDOM % $length  )) # regard initial length
  echo "random number "$randomnumber" -> "${a[$randomnumber]}
  unset a[$randomnumber]
  a=(${a[@]}) # rearranges the indexes
  sleep 2 
done
```

At least there will be some overhead selecting/creating random numbers for indexes that have already been unset if you not regard indexes already removed. endless loops are then still possible if the $RANDOM generation does not function properly and does not return a number in a range. This behavior increases with the length of the array.

Anyway that was an awesome question :)

Comment: Need double quotes inside () in `a=(${a[@]})` to prevent word splitting.