# How to preserve $@ and still use shift

Tags: bash, shell

I want to obtain few command line options into a parent script and pass the original arguments to a child script. I tried the below script and shift seems to empty out $@. Would need some help here.

```
while [[ $# > 0 ]] ; do
    case $1 in
        abc)
            var=$2; shift;
        ;;
        def)
            foo=$2; shift;
        ;;
        *)
    esac
    shift
done
echo "> empty: $@" 
source another.sh "$@"


~/:$ bash x.sh abc ddef def ghi abc hij def abc
```

Comment: Copy array $@ in another one and use the other: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24323275/3776858

Comment: Ha ha, worked. Thanks, it's been ages and was struggling a bit.

Comment: Copying removes quotes?

Comment: s="$@"
ss=("${s[@]}")
echo $ss

Comment: Use this to copy special array $@: `s=( "$@" )`

Comment: Is there a reason you use `shift` other than to keep track of what you've already seen? There are other options.

Comment: That's the only reason, to keep track of what I've seen

Answer (score 1):

Copy array $@ in another one and use the other: [How to copy an array in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24323275/3776858)
Use this to copy special array $@: `s=( "$@" )`