# Making a copy of command line arguments inside a function

Tags: bash

Currently at work on the following version of Bash:

```
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

My current script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function main() {
  local commands=$@
  for command in ${commands[@]} ; do
    echo "command arg: $command"
  done
}

if [[ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" == "$0" ]]; then
  set -e
  main $@
fi
```

In simple terms, this script will only exec `main` if it's the script being called, similar to Python's `if __name__ == '__main__'` convention.

In the `main` function, I'm simply looping over all the command variables, but quote escaping isn't happening as expected:

```
$ tests/simple /bin/bash -c 'echo true'
command arg: /bin/bash
command arg: -c
command arg: echo
command arg: true
```

The last argument here should get parsed by Bash as a single argument, nevertheless it is split into individual words.

What am I doing wrong? I want `echo true` to show up as a single argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the right output except for the `'echo true'` part which is getting word split.  You need to use double quotes in your code:

```
main "$@"
```

And in the function:

```
function main() {
  local commands=("$@") # need () and double quotes here
  for command in "${commands[@]}" ; do
    echo "command arg: $command"
  done
}
```

The function gets its own copy of `$@` and hence you don't really need to make a local copy of it.

With these changes, we get this output:

```
command arg: /bin/bash
command arg: -c
command arg: echo true
```

---

In general, it is not good to store shell commands in a variable.  See [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

See also:

- [How to copy an array in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417015/how-to-copy-an-array-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely want to do something more like this:

```
function main() {
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]
    do
        echo "$1"
        shift
    done
}

main /bin/bash -c "echo true"
```

The key really being `$#`, which counts the number of command line arguments, (not including the invocation name `$0`). The environment variable `$#` is automatically set to the number of command line arguments. If the function/script was called with the following command line:

```
$ main /bin/bash -c "echo true"
```

`$#` would have the value "3" for the arguments: "/bin/bash", "-c", and "echo true". The last one counts as one argument, because they are enclosed within quotes.

1. The `shift` command "shifts" all command line arguments one position to the left.
2. The leftmost argument is lost (`main`).

Answer (score 0):

Quoting of @ passed to main was your issue, but I thought I would mention that you also do not need to assign the value inside main to use it.
You could do the following:

```
main()
{
  for command
  do
    ...
  done
}

main "$@"
```