# How to assign the @ array to another variable in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

Amongst the answers to [How to copy an array in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417015/how-to-copy-an-array-in-bash), the solution for copying an array from one variable to another is `arrayClone=("${oldArray[@]}")`.

However, what if the array I need to copy is the list of arguments, `@`?

A simple test script like:

```
#! /bin/bash

argsCopy=("${@[@]}")
```

Fails with an error:

> line 3: ${@[@]}: bad substitution

Comment: Keep in mind that `"$@"` is from POSIX sh (and shells prior), whereas arrays are a more recent extension. Thus, it's not accurate to think of there being an array named `@`; it's more accurate that arrays are a separate and distinct (newer!) language feature having syntax inspired by the baseline-POSIX syntax of `"$@"` and `"$*"` as mechanisms for accessing the current context's list of command-line arguments.

Answer (score 7):

By way of experimentation, it appears that `argsCopy=("$@")` is sufficient.

When I run the following via `./test.sh 1 2 3\ 4`,

```
#! /bin/bash

set -x
argsCopy=("$@")
echo "${argsCopy[@]}" > /dev/null
```

it outputs:

```
+ argsCopy=("$@")
+ echo 1 2 '3 4'
```

However, like many things in sh/bash, I can't explain what rules of the language cause this to work, or under what circumstances it might end up failing.

Comment: ...and btw, it's not legal sh at all, it's **only** bash/ksh/&c. that support arrays.

Comment: ...as for the relevant syntax rules, see the ["Special Parameters" section of the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, all very helpful notes!

Comment: The key bit in the manual is the explanation that `"$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" …`. Definitely an odd inconsistency I wouldn't expect to find in other languages, but I guess that's part of why these parameters are documented specially…

Comment: Yup; that kind of misalignment is what decades of backwards compatibility (and syntax for newly-added features being carved out of unspecified space) gets you. :/

Comment: (that said, after setting `someArray=( "first item" "second item" )`, the expansion of `"${someArray[@]}"` is equivalent to `"${someArray[0]}" "${someArray[1]}"` -- with each array element as a separate word in the expansion, so syntax between `"$@"` and `${someArray[@]}"` is at least consistent-ish in that respect; `"$@"` not containing `"$0"` is easily defensible from a reasonable-behavior-in-common-use-cases perspective, but it does break the symmetry).