# Copy elements from an array to another preserving embedded spaces

Tags: arrays, bash

Consider having an array which is as follows:

```
array=("BMW E46" "Ford Mustang" "Toyota GT86")
```

Running the following command proves that it has 3 elements:

```
echo ${#array[@]} # outputs 3
```

Now I will remove an element from the initial array:

```
unset array[0]
```

While this will remove the element from my array, the indices will remain the same:

```
echo ${!array[@]} # output: 1 2
```

My way of dealing with this problem (normally) is to just type `array=(${array[@]})` but in this case, running the command will result in my elements being parsed as `('Ford' 'Mustang' ...)`.
Is there a way of fixing the indices without messing up the array elements?

Comment: This might help: [How to copy an array in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19417015/3776858)

Comment: There is no direct way to reorder the indices, without copying to another array

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks. I had searched similar questions but hadn't found this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose `${array[@]}` in double-quotes so that each element will be retained as a separate field.

```
$ array=("BMW E46" "Ford Mustang" "Toyota GT86")
$ unset array[0]
$ array=("${array[@]}")
$ declare -p array
declare -a array=([0]="Ford Mustang" [1]="Toyota GT86")
```

Comment: Wow. I can't believe the solution was this easy! I was trying different methods for HOURS! Thanks a whole bunch.