# sliced arrays flatten to len=1?

Tags: arrays, bash

I am pulling my hair out manipulating arrays in bash.  I have an array of strings, which contain spaces.  I would like an array containing all but the first element of my input array.

```
input=("first string" "second string" "third string")
echo ${#input[@]}
# len(input)=3
# get slice of all except for first element of input
slice=${input[@]:1}
echo ${#slice[@]}
# expect 2, but get 1
echo $slice
# second string third string
# slice should contain ("second string" "third string"), but instead is "second string third string"
```

Slicing the array clearly works to eliminate the first element, but the result appears to be a concatenation of all remaining strings, rather than an array.  Is there a way to slice an array in bash and get an array as a result?

(sorry, I'm not new to bash, but I've never used it for much before, and I can't find any documentation showing why my slice is flattened)

Comment: You should handle `slice` as an array, not as a scalar parameter. Try `slice=("${input[@]:1}")`.

Comment: You need to say `slice=("${input[@]:1}")`, not `slice=${input[@]:1}`.

Comment: See: [How to copy an array in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19417015/3776858) and [How can I remove an element from an array completely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68322/74329)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should [always quote variable expansions](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting). Be *very* wary of any solution that relies on unquoted expansions. ShellCheck.net is a great tool for catching bugs related to quoting (among many other issues).

To your specific issue, `slice=${input[@]:1}` does not do what you want. It defines a single scalar variable `slice` rather than an array, meaning the array expansion (denoted by the `[@]`) will first be munged into a single string using the current `IFS`. Here's a demo:

```
$ arr=(1 2 '3 4')
$ IFS=,
$ var="${arr[@]:1}"
$ echo "$var"
2,3 4
```

To instead declare and populate an [array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) use the `=()` notation, like so:

```
$ var=("${arr[@]:1}")
$ printf '%s\n' "${var[@]}"
2
3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are reset, element 1 is now element 0:

```
slice=("${input[@]:1}")
```

Element and index are removed, the first element is now index 1, not index 0:

```
unset input[0]
```

`${#slice[@]}` or `${#input[@]}` will now be 1 less than the previous value of `${#input[@]}`. Starting out with three elements in `slice`, the values of `"${!slice[@]}"` and `"${!input[@]}"`, will be `0 1` and `1 2` respectively (for either the first or second approach)

If you don't quote `slice=("${input[@]:1}")`, each array element is split on whitespace, creating many more elements.